# Why does my raspberry pi keep halting?

Tags: usb, headless

My Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) (Headless) keeps stopping all connections (Pinging and trying to connect to Shell In A Box and ssh) after 5-10 mins of being on. It requires to be rebooted in order to work again.

Btw it uses a usb for its root filesystem and the Power source is 5V 2A and the USB connected is 16GB Lexar USB and its connected by ethernet straight to a router and there is nothing else connected

Comment: This should be closed as off topic under the general SE "problem which cannot be reproduced" reason

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the firewall on your router (and Pi if it's running one)

check the SSH config for timeout settings

or try another powersource, I know yours is up to spec but cable/power source can vary wide. You wouldn't believe how many times the problem can be traced back to the power on Pi related issues.

It could have something to do with the USB drive, if you have a spare SD card lying around you could try and use it to troubleshoot this issue a bit further.

Lastly, check the log files for clues.

Comment: Turns out It has been running all the time its just its accepting from a different ip to the one it should be accepting from. I have set it to be a connection from the startup config on the fat32 partition of the microsd so is there anyway of keeping it on that ip? btw it keeps renewing the ip to the different one every 1444 seconds

Comment: nvm its fixed now ;)